# run cat command for all the files in the directory given in argument of the script file and out put with the name given as second argument

Tags: linux, bash, file, concatenation, cat

I run the following code for concatenating files in a directory given as the argument for the script file in bash

```
for i in $* 
do

    cat $* > /home/christy/Documents/filetest/catted.txt

done
```

This produce the error

```
cat: /home/christy/Documents/filetest/catted.txt: input file is output file
```

Comment: Are you sure you use `$*`? I get an empty string in my bash. Also, where do you use the variable `i`? Do you want to concatenate teh same things more times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are at least 4 things wrong with your script....

Firstly, your loop will set the value of `i` to the name of each file in succession, so you would want to actually use `i` inside your loop, like this:

```
for i in $*
    cat "$i"  ....somewhere
done
```

Secondly, if you use the `>` redirection, each file will land *exactly on top* of the previous one, so you should really use the `>>` redirection will *append* the current file to the end of the previous one like this

```
for i in $*
do
    cat "$i"   >>  ...somewhere
done
```

Thirdly, I think you should use double-quoted `"$@"` to get all your command-line arguments, rather than plain `$*`

```
for i in "$@"
...
```

Fourthly, you can achieve the exact effect I think you want with this simpler command:

```
cat "$@" > /home/christy/Documents/filetest/catted.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `cat` a file back onto itself.  That's what "input file is output file" means.  Because catted.txt shows up in your list of arguments to cat, it is going to try to cat to itself.  So, move catted.txt to somewhere other than the source directory.